# PHP - include function with define constants not working properly

Tags: php, constants, include

**Hello all...** *It was all working properly, but suddenly two days before something went wrong. I really don't know what went wrong. Tried all possible solutions from internet and double checked all paths and the paths and files are good.* ***But the problem still persist.*** Please help me.

### THE PROBLEM IS

I have a config file in which i have defined some constants and values.

files structure is

```
htdocs
|--tbook
    |-- index.php
    |-- config.php
    |-- scrap.css
    |-- <some other folders>
          |-- <some other files>
```

file name : **config.php**

```
<?php
      define("HOST_NAME", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
      define("ROOT_DIR", "http://".HOST_NAME."/tbook/");
        ....
      /* { other constants definition }*/
?>
```

**Now I am trying to include this into my index.php and trying to use these constants to include or link other files.** *(I am using this method for future sake if i want to change the directory of files, I only need to change the directory names in define values rather than in all files).*

file name : **index.php**

```
<?php
   include "./config.php";
   include ROOT_DIR."someother_php.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ROOT_DIR . "scrap.css" ?>">
</head>
```

The problems is, Now if I load the index.php the style sheet should be rendered, as it should, **But the style is not rendered..**

**any file link I create with the help of these defined constants are not working.**
but all the direct/absolute links work.

I double checked by copying the links generated by echoing the defined constants, and tried to open it in explored and the file opens. so the file/file path is not a problem at all.

The `<?php echo ROOT_DIR . "scrap.css" ?>` prints as

`http://localhost/tbook/scrap.css`

Only the include function, or the links generated with echoing the constants are not working.
***Please Help Me, to identify the Problem...***
I am using **XAMPP for windows** with **PHP 7.3.28**

Comment: did you check if there is a path issue with config.php and the current file where you are including?

Comment: yes i have. The file where I am including is my `index.php`. `config.php` is also in the root folder only. all other content in index displays. and if i echo the define variable that also prints well. but only the generated links are not working properly.

Comment: <?php echo ROOT_DIR . "scrap.css" ?>  can you try to print what exactly it is receiving? and where scrap.css located?

Comment: That doesn't look correct. It might not be the cause of the CSS not loading, but it should cause issues either way. You're trying to include PHP files through a HTTP request, which won't work (since the PHP code will then be executed on the server, only returning the response, not the actual PHP code). You should have two different constants, one with the URL and one with a local file path. You can also check the network tab in the developer console to see what URL it actually is trying to load the CSS from.

Comment: @user703894 : I have updated the question with the file structure and echo prints.

Comment: @M.Eriksson can you please post an example of how to define two different constants as you described. I not quite sure about how!

Comment: include "./config.php"; change this to include "config.php"; to see if that works. and your echo result is correct as per directory structure you posted. you can check the exact css link by inspecting the page, that may help

Comment: <?php
include "./config.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ROOT_DIR . "scrap.css" ?>">
</head>
<body>
    <span class='err'>Here goes the text with css applied from scrap.css</span>
</body>

</html>  thisworks for me provided all the files in the same dir and scrap.css has the following css .err{
    color:red;
} using wamp

Comment: @user703894. with @M.Eriksson's answer I have changed `$_SERVER` variable from `HTTP_HOST` to `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to acquire the file root. now the css works from echoing the constants. but not other files
```<?php
include  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/tbook/config.php";
// in this config file API_DB_PATH is defined.

include  API_DB_PATH. "class.mysqli.php";
// this contains class MySql definition

function get_details($id)
{
    $db = new MySql();  
    // this throw error : 
    // Uncaught Error: Class 'MySql' not found in D:\WebProjects\..\..\....
    ....
```